How do i log successful server initialization in a goroutine?
http.ListenAndServe(), if there aren't any error, block the execution so the following lines won't be executed.
go func() {
        err := http.ListenAndServe("127.0.0.1:9090", nil)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            return
        }
        fmt.Println(Success) // Not executed
    }()

select{}


I could log the success message outside the goroutine but it's not ideal since it can be executed before a possible error occur.

The only initialization that can fail is creating the listener.  Break that out as a separate step, log and then start the listen loop.
l, err := net.Listen("tcp", "127.0.0.1:9090")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
fmt.Println("success")
log.Fatal(http.Serve(l, nil)) // runs until server fails.

